# apache commons CollectionUtils assertion

Tags: java, assertions

I guess the question was already posted, unfortunately I couldn't find a related topic, so if you know the related questions, please let me know the links.

I'm new using the apache commons library and assertions. I have a very simple assertion .. but I can't make it work and I don't know the reason.

I have my class **ChannelComponent**

```
public class ChannelComponent{
public ChannelComponent(String topicName, CType mode, Class<? extends IEvent> eventType) {
        this.topicName = topicName;
        this.mode = mode;
        this.eventType = eventType;
    }
...
}
```

Another class **CentralRegistry**, which contains a List of ChannelComponents

```
public class CentralRegistry {

private List<ChannelComponent> channels = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<ChannelComponent>());

...

public List<ChannelComponent> getChannels() {
        return channels;
    }

}
```

When I run the unitTest, the CentralRegistry creates a channelComponent with the values

```
[topicName:TemperatureEventTopic ,comType: ONEP_ONEC ,eventClass: TemperatureEvent]
```

In my unitTest I have:

public class CMonitorUnitTest {

```
private List<ChannelComponent> expectedChannel  = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<ChannelComponent>());

public void setUp() throws Exception {
expectedChannel.add(new ChannelComponent("TemperatureEventTopic", CType.ONEP_ONEC, TemperatureEvent.class));
}

@Test
public void test(){

assertTrue(CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(expectedChannel,centralRegistry.getChannels()));
}
```

I got an AssertionError, why? what is missing?

Comment: I believe `isEqualCollection()` uses object reference equality, not `equals()` equality. Why not just use the built-in `assertTrue(expectedChannel.equals(centralRegistry.getChannels()))`, or `assertEqual(expectedChannel, centralRegistry.getChannels())`?

Comment: It works with the assertions you mentioned, I just thought that I should use the CollectionUtils, because I had a similar example but using Maps, so I though that I should do that too :/. But now I see that is not necessary to do that, I can only use the simple built-in.

Comment: Is still confussing to me what assertion to use, but I will keep doing small examples. Thank you!